# Problem with X-Content-Type-Options in node.js

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, header, x-content-type-options

I'm working on a To-Do List project with node.js and I met a problem with the header X-Content-Type-Options in my browser console which prevent myself from reading stylesheet or javascript script.

To give you an idea, here the screen capture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYWgx.png)

I tried to relsolve this problem by adding a .htaccess file in my project but there is nothing to do. Here what I put in my file:

Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: I'm not really into node.js, but I think it would be helpful to post the error you get here too (preferably in English) and to give the image a proper description :) - why do you set "nosniff" anyway?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it's the first time I post on Stack OverFlow but alas, in my browser console, the problem is written in French. But I continue my researches maybe one day I'll find the results :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved my problem: in fact, in the ejs ' header document where we put the link, I should have added the access path to server.

So I put:

Same thing for the javascript file.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/name_of_the_folder">